# What is being returned by this GroupJoin in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am having some trouble understanding GroupJoin in C# and was wondering if someone could clarify.

Say I have two lists of this object

```
public class Item
{
     public int Id { get; set;}

     public decimal Amount { get; set;}
}

var itemListOne = new List<Item>(){
    new Item{
        Id = 1,
        Amount = 100
    },
    new Item{
        Id = 2,
        Amount = 200
    },
    new Item{
        Id = 3,
        Amount = 300
    },
}

var itemListTwo = new List<Item>(){
    new Item{
        Id = 1,
        Amount = 400
    },
    new Item{
        Id = 2,
        Amount = 500
    }
}
```

I then am calling a LINQ query like this

```
var result = (from listOneItem in itemListOne
              join listTwoItem in itemListTwo on listOneItem.Id equals listTwoItem.id into joinedItems
              from joinedItem in joinedItems.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select joinedItem != null ? joinedItem.Amount : 0).ToArray();
```

What I was looking for with this code was to join the two lists on their Id fields. Once joined I would select the amount value from the second list of items, and the leftover entry in the first list wouldn't get joined so it would return a 0 into the list.

And this code actually works. When I tested it out I could see he first two entries were 400 and 500. And the third was 0 because the first list has that 3rd item which could not be joined onto the second list. But I don't understand why it works.

I was reading into GroupJoins and I thought it mentioned that the returned value would be entries from the outer list. So I expected to have an array of 100, 200, and 300 because the outer list is itemListOne right? But it looks like it's actually giving me the values from the second list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Linq expression...

```cs
var result = (
        from listOneItem in itemListOne
        join listTwoItem in itemListTwo on listOneItem.Id equals listTwoItem.id into joinedItems
        from joinedItem in joinedItems.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select joinedItem != null ? joinedItem.Amount : 0
    )
    .ToArray();
```

...is equivalent to this:

```cs
decimal[] result = itemListOne
    .GroupJoin(
        inner: itemListTwo,
        outerKeySelector: i1 => i1.Id,
        innerKeySelector: i2 => i2.Id,
        resultSelector  : ( Item i1, IEnumerable<Item> i2Items ) => new { i1, i2Items }
    )
    .SelectMany(
        collectionSelector: t => t.i2Items.DefaultIfEmpty(),     // `t` is the Anonymous Type above.
        resultSelector    : ( t, i2 ) => i2?.Amount ?? 0M
    )
    .ToArray();
```

Notice how the `i1` objects are passed into `GroupJoin`'s `resultSelector` which outputs them into a new anonymously-type object, which then get flattened by `SelectMany`.

---

> Once joined I would select the `Amount` from the second list of items, and the leftover entry in the first list wouldn't get joined so it would return a 0 into the list.

It would, except that you're using `.DefaultIfEmpty()`, so for the final item the expressio `i2Items.DefaultIfEmpty()` evaluates to `null` instead of an empty `IEnumerable<Item>`.

So if you remove `.DefaultIfEmpty` and the `??` bits it still works but outputs only 2 `decimal` values, not 3.

```
decimal[] result = itemListOne
    .GroupJoin(
        inner: itemListTwo,
        outerKeySelector: i1 => i1.Id,
        innerKeySelector: i2 => i2.Id,
        resultSelector  : ( Item i1, IEnumerable<Item> i2Items ) => new { i1, i2Items }
    )
    .SelectMany(
        collectionSelector: t => t.i2Items,     // `t` is the Anonymous Type above.
        resultSelector    : ( t, i2 ) => i2.Amount
    )
    .ToArray();
```

With this simplification, here's what the intermediate results look like after each Linq step:

- `GroupJoin`:

  ```
  new[] {
      new
      {
          i1      = Item( id: 1, Amount: 100 ),
          i2Items = new[] { Item( id: 1, Amount: 400 ), }
      },
      new
      {
          i1      = Item( id: 2, Amount: 200 ),
          i2Items = new[] { Item( id: 2, Amount: 500 ), }
      },
      new
      {
          i1      = Item( id: 3, Amount: 300 ),
          i2Items = new[] { /* empty */ }
      },
  }
  ```
- `SelectMany`:

  ```
  new[] {
      400M,
      500M
  }
  ```

---

Seeming as none of the `i1` objects are used after the `GroupJoin` matching completes you can simplify it further by omitting `i1` from `GroupJoin`'s output:

```cs
decimal[] result = itemListOne
    .GroupJoin(
        inner: itemListTwo,
        outerKeySelector: i1 => i1.Id,
        innerKeySelector: i2 => i2.Id,
        resultSelector  : ( Item i1, IEnumerable<Item> i2Items ) => i2Items
    )
    .SelectMany( i2Items => i2Items )
    .Select( i2 => i2.Amount )
    .ToArray();
```

...and move the `.Select( i2 => i2.Amount )` up into `resultSelector:`

```cs
decimal[] result = itemListOne
    .GroupJoin(
        inner: itemListTwo,
        outerKeySelector: i1 => i1.Id,
        innerKeySelector: i2 => i2.Id,
        resultSelector  : ( Item i1, IEnumerable<Item> i2Items ) => i2Items.Select( i2 => i2.Amount )
    )
    .SelectMany( amounts => amounts )
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Ahhhh I think I see now. So after the GroupJoin, we pretty much have a list of all the entries from list one. And each entry in that list contains another list of all the entries from list two that it was joined on.

So for example, if there was another entry in list two with an ID of 1, then the GroupJoin would have two entries joined onto the entry with ID 1 in list 1

Comment: @William Pretty much: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IonqNH

Answer (score 1):

This query basically represents equivalent of [SQL left join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/left-join-right-join-operations-microsoft-access-sql), where `joinedItem` represents the second (right) part of the join, so you actually will get `null` (hence the need for null check - `joinedItem != null`) for unmatched entry from the first (left) part of the join (`Id == 3`). If you want to access data for the left part - use `listOneItem`. For example for LINQ-to-Objects:

```cs
var result = (from listOneItem in itemListOne
    join listTwoItem in itemListTwo on listOneItem.Id equals listTwoItem.Id into joinedItems
    from joinedItem in joinedItems.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {
        Id = listOneItem.Id,
        LeftAmount = listOneItem.Amount,
        RightAmount = joinedItem?.Amount ?? 0})
    .ToArray();
```

Will result in the following:

| Id | LeftAmount | RightAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 400 |
| 2 | 200 | 500 |
| 3 | 300 | 0 |